# Is the verb "be" needed in each phrase joined with "or" or "and"?

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions

Is the second "is" required in the following statement:

> An error will be thrown if index **is** equal to or **is** greater than limit.

Comment: I would say no, but if the clauses that make up the "or" correlation are long, it's helpful to repeat it.

Comment: No, the second *is* is allowed, but it is not required.

Comment: This is Off Topic proofreading. @Jin - it's grammatically "valid" to repeat the verb, [and there are 4 written instances in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+equal+to+or+is+greater%22). But [here are 303,000 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+equal+to+or+greater%22) that *don't* repeat the verb, so you can easily see what *most* speakers/writers do in this context. So your example isn't very "natural", but the main reason for that is actually because *index* and *limit* are normally preceded by the indefinite article ***the***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second "is" is not required; but it is helpful to connect the second phrase with the principal part of the sentence, when the first phrase is long one.